# reading java property value with spaces into one variable

Tags: java, properties

Hello my problem is as follows:
i have a property fiel with a startconfig for external program to run from java:

```
   # Standardauswahl falls keine PlayerType übergeben wurden 
   Default = 1
   # Liste der gültigen PlayerTypes
   PlayerTypes = Human,MCTS,TMM,Random,Value
   StartConfig = \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_13\\bin\\javaw.exe\" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/Users/djdeejay/git/myGit/com.djdeejay.cowTrade.client.standaloneplayer.application/bin/log4j.xml -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath  [..... some parameter deleted.....] 0.0-RC1.jar;C:\\Users\\djdeejay\\git\\myGit\\de.thWildau.cowTrade.server\\lib\\slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar;C:\\Users\\djdeejay\\git\\myGit\\de.thWildau.cowTrade.server\\lib\\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar;C:\\Users\\djdeejay\\git\\myGit\\de.thWildau.cowTrade.server\\lib\\log4j-1.2.16.jar com.djdeejay.cowTrade.client.standaloneplayer.application.RandomPlayerApplication %1 %2 %3
```

when i load the properties as follows

```
cmd = this.serverSettings.getPlayerTypeSetting("StartConfig");

@Override
public String getPlayerTypeSetting(String key) {
    return this.startPlayerTypeSettingsProp.getProperty(key);
}
```

java  cutting startconfig after the first space:

Cannot run program """C:\Program" when its in doublequotes or  Cannot run program ""C:\Program":

i have tried several variants with "", with escaping and so on nothing gives my needed result

how do i config getproperty to read until EOL?

cheers

Comment: Are you sure `getProperty` is at fault here? Try printing `cmd` before executing it. The [Properties#load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) documentation says properties *are* read until newline, so that should be fine.

Comment: You are right the problem is Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); my output is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_1%3\bin\javaw.exe" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/Users/djdeejay/git/myGit/com.d.... i´ll try  command in front of it

Comment: You need to use [Runtime#exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) with `String[] cmdArray` to cleanly separate command from arguments.

Comment: @mabi, thx its solved the problem occurd in the runcmd but the output of the ioexception was missleading ...

Comment: and by the way thx the troll for downvoting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the `getProperty` call is alright. But the usage as a single string in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` uses the default whitespace Tokenizer to split the string into command and argument.

To do this yourself, first split the string manually and then pass it to [Runtime#exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

```
String startCmdLine = this.serverSettings.getPlayerTypeSetting("StartConfig");
int cmdEndPos = startCmdLine.indexOf("javaw.exe") + "javaw.exe".length();
String cmd = startCmdLine.substring(0, cmdEndPos);
String args = startCmdLine.substring(cmdEndPos);

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ cmd, args });
```

Though I really advise you to take advantage of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable if you just want to start a known java binary. That way you can reduce that to a set of parameters in the property file.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your spaces with: "\u0020"

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
     StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(String input);
```

See [doc here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)